# Springboot: How can I perform an integration test with real dependencies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, integration-testing

I'm starting to learn both Java and Spring boot now, and I'm having some problems with dependency injection in integration tests. I have a class under ***src/main/java/com/rfd/domain/services*** called TransactionService, which is marked as @Service and which has another dependencies, one of them a repository created by Spring boot. When I launch the application, it is launched correctly so I assume the dependencies are being resolved correctly. This is the summarized class:

```
package com.rfd.domain.services;

import allNeededImports

@Service
public class TransactionsService {

    @Autowired
    private KambiTransactionRepository kambiTransactionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionFactory transactionFactory;

    public List<Transaction> retrieveTransactions(String couponExternalId) throws InvalidTransactionException {
        // someCode
    }
}
```

and now, I have a TransactionsServiceTests class under ***/src/test/java/com/rfd/integrationtests/domain/services***:

```
package com.rfd.integrationtests.domain.services;
import allNeededImports

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@DataMongoTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-integrationtest.properties")
public class TransactionsServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionsService transactionsService;

    @Test
    public void retrieveTransactions_happyPathMultipleTransactions_transactionsRetrieved() throws InvalidTransactionException {
        // test code
    }
```

When I try to launch the tests, I receive the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.rfd.domain.services.TransactionsService'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I have tried to create my own @TestConfiguration class, in which I create a method marked with @Bean and returning a new instance of TransactionService, and it works. However, the error now is for the KambiTransactionRepository dependency, and I don't have an implementation of it because it is given by spring boot:

```
package com.rfd.infrastructure.repositories;

import com.rfd.infrastructure.models.KambiTransaction;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface KambiTransactionRepository extends MongoRepository<KambiTransaction, String> {

    List<KambiTransaction> findByCouponRef(String couponRef);
}
```

**QUESTION**
How can I execute the integration test using the dependency resolution of the main code?

Comment: Is  Main.class in @SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class), your @SpringBootApplication class?

Comment: Yes, it is the @SpringBootApplication annotated class

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` and the `@Data` tests are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Didn't know that, but even removing @SpringBootTest, the problem is still the same

Comment: It worked! I removed the DataMongoTest and it seem it can resolve dependencies now. However, I was using the DataMongoTest to use an in-memory database instead of the real one. But that is another problem. Thanks @M.Deinum!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @M.Deinum remarked in comments, `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataMongoTest` are mutually exclusive, so removing `@DataMongoTest` solved the problem.

**However**, if you still want to use the `@DataMongoTest` annotation, you can use this sentence:

```
@DataMongoTest(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(Service.class))
```

That way, all classes that are annotated with `@Component` will be loaded and autowired. This includes (among others) `@Service`, `@Repository` and `@Controller`.

Comment: you mean: `@DataMongoTest(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(Component.class))`

Comment: But this way its also loading real database configuration, how to exclude that ?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add test for my storage service and I needed to autowire `MongoRepository`. The answer to this question did not solve my problem. However I found a solution and will share here in case someone else needs. I solved it as following:

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyEntity, String> {
}
```

Entity:

```
@Document(collection = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class StorageServiceImpl implements StorageService {
    private final MyRepository repository;

    public StorageServiceImpl(MyRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
...
}
```

Test:

```
@Import(ObjectMapperConfiguration.class)
@DataMongoTest
class StorageServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    private StorageService storageService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        storageService = new StorageServiceImpl(repository);
        var entity = new MyEntity();
        repository.save(entity);
    }

    @Test
    void create() {
        assertEquals(1, repository.count());
        var entity = storageService.create();
        assertEquals(2, repository.count());
    }
...
}
```

Test Config:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

Test Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
}
```