# Spring 3.x Integration Test with Embedded MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing, embedded-mongodb

I'm trying to create a Integration test of a Spring Boot controller running against a MongoDB embedded database with Spring 3.x but I have been unable to configure it correctly. As I have read if I'm using @SpringBootTest and @AutoConfigureDataMongo it will try to connect with a real database instead of searching for the embbeded one.

I have seen this responses:

1. [Manually Start MongoDD 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73852619/6645336)
2. [Manually Start MongoDD 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54244131/6645336)

in stackoverflow to manually start the embedded database.

But I cannot use this code with *de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo* version **4.9.2** since the code has changes and those classes are not longer available.

Anyone can help me to manually start the database in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm went through a similiar problem, try adding in the test properties the following snippet:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It's still trying to connect to to the real database instead of the embedded one. If I stop the real database it throws an exception.


com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket.

When the realdatabase is started I can see the embedded one starting too but the code is not waiting for the embeeded one since the port is random. I don't know how to comunicate the two.